# Removing an EventListener from an object decided via an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, event-listener

I am making a simple calculator for an assignment in my IT-Class. It has 3 textboxes where the user can add his numbers, and the boxes start with a "0" inside of them, to show that the user is supposed to write numbers here. What I wanna do, is have this zero go away as the user puts focus on the box.

Since I have 3 boxes, I wanted to make the EventListener call up a function that removes the text and the Eventlistener, instead of writing the same code 3 times.

Using an array containing the different textboxes I managed to call them up, and change the text as I wanted, but the EventListener isn't being removed, so the text the user writes in is being removed when they focus on the textbox again

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//The Array containing all the TextFields
var textFieldArr:Array = new Array(txtNumber1,txtNumber2,txtNumber2)

function onFocus(i:int){
    return function (evt:FocusEvent){
        textFieldArr[i].text = "";
        textFieldArr[i].removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus(i))
    }
}

//Calls up the onFocus function and declares variable i
txtNumber1.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus(0));
txtNumber2.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus(1));
txtNumber3.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus(2));


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event listener isn't being removed, because when you call onFocus(i) within the removeEventListener param, you are being returned a new function, and not the function that was originally being triggered by the event. The other problem with your code is that 'i' does not exist in the listener function you have declared -- you need to use only the properties of evt to figure out which text field to target, and the correct event listener to remove.

The common/correct way to do this is to use a event-accepting function, and listen to each text field with it. You don't even need the array anymore unless you have some other use for it.

```
function onFocusIn(evt:FocusEvent):void{
    trace("onFocusIn("+evt.target+")");
    var focusedField:TextField = TextField(evt.target);
    if(focusedField){
        focusedField.text = "";
        focusedField.removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
    }
}

txtNumber1.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
txtNumber2.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
txtNumber3.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
```

Comment: Thank's a bunch!Your explanation cleared everything up for me!

Comment: Question: in your 'removeEventListener' line why is the listener function 'onFocusEvent' instead of 'onFocusIn'?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that; it was a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Listener is not removed, because `onFocus` returns on each invocation new `Function` instance.

You might try use `target` property of `FocusEvent` class:

```
var textFieldArr:Array = new Array(txtNumber1,txtNumber2,txtNumber2)

function onFocus(evt:FocusEvent){
    TextField(evt.target).text = "";
    TextField(evt.target).removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus)
}

//Calls up the onFocus function and declares variable i
txtNumber1.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus);
txtNumber2.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus);
txtNumber3.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus);
```